# Database Table Filtration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

UPDATE: Sorry I'm new on here so i did not know the guidelines

This is what i have done so far

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>AJAX filter demo</title>
</head>

<body> 
  <h1>Temporary Database</h1>

   <table id="employees">
    <thead>
    <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Car</th>
      <th>Language</th>
      <th>Nights</th>
      <th>Student</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
     <script>
    function makeTable(data){
     var tbl_body = "";
      $.each(data, function() {
        var tbl_row = "";
        $.each(this, function(k , v) {
          tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
        })
        tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";                 
      })

      return tbl_body;
  }

  function updateEmployees(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "submit.php",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(records){
        $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
      }
      });
      }

    updateEmployees();
   </script> 
 </body> 
  </html>
```

which outputs the table now in regards of client-side filtration i think is what I'm looking for. how would i go about filtering each column with a dropdown to output specific data unlike if i had a checkbox?
Thank you

Comment: While this is fine as a journal entry, it's really not specific enough to be a Stack Overflow question. The number one question here is **What have you tried?** and if you can't answer that with code it means you've got a bit more work to do to formulate a question. It doesn't matter if your code is complete, just that it expresses the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: ok just corrected it i apologize I'm new to this @tadman

Comment: No need for an apology. Your inclusion of code is what matters here. Since you're using jQuery, you might want to look through the [jQuery UI site](https://jqueryui.com) or see if there's any [jQuery plugins](https://plugins.jquery.com) that might help with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP to generate the table and html, then possibly use the jquery plugin https://datatables.net/, it allows you to easily create dynamic tables using javascript and jquery. It will save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Avoid posting "only link" answers as they may get deleted

Comment: thank you sorry new to this